# podria hacer esto en un analizador sintactico en el lenguaje de programacion javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer un analizador sintactito en JAVASCRIPT, queria saber si usando este metodo podria ser factible? ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con el lenguaje. le agregue los if else para ver si podria funcionar sin embargo tengo mis dudas acerca de lo mismo ya que no tengo mucha base en el lenguaje de programacion

```
var currentToken = [
    {type: "_palabra_reservada", value: "let"},
    {type: "identificador_", value: "c"},
    {type: "operador_", value: "="},
    {type: "constante_", value: "6"},
    {type: "operador_", value: "*"},
    {type: "constante_", value: "9"}
]
//let c = 6 * 9
var type="type"; 
var value="value";

let nextTokens = {
    _pr: ["_id"],
    _id: ["_op"],
    _op: ["_const"],
    _const: ["_op"]
     }
```

parte nueva del codigo

```
         if(currenToken[0].value == _pr ) {
             console.log("continue");
               }
            else if
             ("error de sintaxis falta una palabra reservada como let, var 
           o const"); 

             else if  (currenToken[1].value == _id ){
                console.log("continue")
                  }

               else if 
          ("error de sintaxis falta el identificador de la variable");
```

Comment: Tienes errores de sintaxis. Por ejemplo, después de: `if(...) {` no cierras la llave y pones un `else` y, definitivamente, no se entiende lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: el codigo es solo un borrador. estoy intentando hacer un analizador sintactico en javascript, en el array current token tengo esta expresion let c = 6*9; quisiera poder analizar el orden de eso con respecto a la reglas de JS para que si en un caso tenga por ejemplo let=9; me diga error porque falta el identificador de la variable... entonces trato de hacer un condicional.. si la primera palabra del array es palabra reserva como var, let, const entonces que corra y si no que de un error, luego si la segunda palabra de la expresion es un id esta bien si no es entonces que diga error de sintaxis

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres es algo como [esprima](https://github.com/jquery/esprima)

Comment: accedi al ink de esprima y no, mas que todo es analizar un codigo simple como por ejemplo var num = 1; y evaluar cada parte del mismo para ver si cumple con el orden de reglas segun JS. Primero una variable/let/const luego el identificador que es el nombre de la variable, luego el simbolo de asignacion, la constante y por ultimo otro simbolo que es para finalizar la sentencia (al menos en el ejemplo que di) puede haber otros como let nombre, var numero; o let nombre="Luis"; o let nombre=var nombre